# how can i add space between table border and text using html only?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, web-deployment

[image: the image is the final output I want]

HI can someone pls help me I am new to code and this is my college assignment in which we are not supposed to use CSS, only using HTML how can I add space between text and table-border.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>TABLE</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <TABLE BORDER="5" CELLSPACING="4" CELLPADDING="3">
      <TR BGCOLOR="BLUE">
        <TH ALIGN="CENTER" HEIGHT="20">
          <FONT SIZE="4" COLOR="WHITE"> <u>First Name</u>
        <TH ALIGN="CENTER" HEIGHT="20">
          <FONT SIZE="4" COLOR="WHITE"> <u>Last Name</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD> <u>Keith</u>
        <TD><u>Richards</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Mick</u>
        <TD><u>Jagger</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Bill</u>
        <TD><u>Wyman</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Ron</u>
        <TD><u>Wood</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Charlie</u>
        <TD><u>Watts</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Mick</u>
        <TD><u>Taylor</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Brian</u>
        <TD><u>Jones</u>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>

  </HTML>
```

my code-

Comment: Where is the space expected to be? It is not clear from the image - unless you refer to the column headers?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - there are unclosed `TD` elements ~ they should ALL be closed with `</td>`. The same holds true for the `TH` tags

Comment: You can use `&nbsp;` to insert a single space or multiple to add larger spaces. Alternatively do as per the `th` and use `align=center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TD> <u>&nbspKeith</u> </TD>
```

Try using &nbsp should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

To add space between cell content and cell wall you can use the `cellpadding` attribute in `table` tag.

> The HTML  cellpadding Attribute is used to specify the space
> between the cell content and cell wall. The cellpadding attribute is
> set in terms of pixels.

Refer: [cellpadding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-table-cellpadding-attribute/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>TABLE</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <TABLE BORDER="5" CELLSPACING="4" CELLPADDING="10">
      <TR BGCOLOR="BLUE">
        <TH ALIGN="CENTER" HEIGHT="20">
          <FONT SIZE="4" COLOR="WHITE"> <u>First Name</u>
        <TH ALIGN="CENTER" HEIGHT="20">
          <FONT SIZE="4" COLOR="WHITE"> <u>Last Name</u>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Keith</u></TD> 
        <TD><u>Richards</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Mick</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Jagger</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Bill</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Wyman</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Ron</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Wood</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Charlie</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Watts</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="ORANGE">
        <TD><u>Mick</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Taylor</u></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR BGCOLOR="YELLOW">
        <TD><u>Brian</u></TD>
        <TD><u>Jones</u></TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>

  </HTML>
```

Comment: it is not supporting in html 5